# Django. Adding objects that have two foreign keys to the same class

Tags: python, django, web

my problem is that when you want to add objects to a class that contains two foreign keys to other (equal) classes. First add an object of the class to which the foreign key refers. And when you want to select the same object but in another field, it does not appear.

models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Match(models.Model):
     home = models.ForeignKey(Team)
     away = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

So .. How do I do if I want local and away to be the same teams without having to update the admin page when I create the local team?

Thanks!

Agu

Answer (score 0):

Short of refreshing the page, the only other way I can think of doing this is by adding `raw_id_fields` to the admin.py. This will allow a popup to show up when selecting a ForeignKey, so it should let you create a Team and select it without refreshing the page.

Source

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields